# I cant do wait my code until a toggle animation in finished in jQuery UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to develop a menu with a jQuery UI animation to show the different submenus and I need wait until the toggle effect to hidde the control is finished to change the content of the menu. Now my code change the content of the menu during the toggle effect.
The secondary menu to show is inside the 'div' with the id=#secondary-menu-wrap. Inside this I have some 'ul' whoose 'li' visibility i need to change when the toggle effect to hide the "#secondary-menu-wrap" is finished (line 3 of the code). Now, the code is changin the content of the "#secondary-menu-wrap" during this toggle effect (line 4 runs before the toggle effect of the line 3 is finished).

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('#header-menu > li').click(function(){
        jQuery('#secondary-menu-wrap').toggle('slide',{direction: 'up'}, 500);
                jQuery('.secondary-menu > li').css('display','none');               
switch(this.id) {
    case 'menu-item-group':
        jQuery('#secondary-menu_group > li').css('display','block');
        break;
    case 'menu-item-research':
        jQuery('#secondary-menu_research > li').css('display','block');
        break;
    case 'menu-item-projects':
        jQuery('#secondary-menu_projects > li').css('display','block');
        break;
    case 'menu-item-publications':
        jQuery('#secondary-menu_publications > li').css('display','block');
        break;
    case 'menu-item-pressroom':
        jQuery('#secondary-menu_pressroom > li').css('display','block');
        break;
    case 'menu-item-formation':
        jQuery('#secondary-menu_formation > li').css('display','block');
        break
} 

    jQuery('#secondary-menu-wrap').toggle('slide',{direction: 'up'}, 500);
        });

        jQuery('.T_logo').click(function(){
        jQuery('.secondary-menu > li').css('display','none'); 
        });
});
```

I tried this two options but without the desired result:

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('#header-menu > li').click(function(){
        jQuery('#secondary-menu-wrap').toggle('slide',{direction: 'up'}, 500,function(){
        jQuery('.secondary-menu > li').css('display','none');
});



switch(this.id) {
    case 'menu-item-group':
        jQuery('#secondary-menu_group > li').css('display','block');
        break;
    case 'menu-item-research':
        jQuery('#secondary-menu_research > li').css('display','block');
        break;
    case 'menu-item-projects':
        jQuery('#secondary-menu_projects > li').css('display','block');
        break;
    case 'menu-item-publications':
        jQuery('#secondary-menu_publications > li').css('display','block');
        break;
    case 'menu-item-pressroom':
        jQuery('#secondary-menu_pressroom > li').css('display','block');
        break;
    case 'menu-item-formation':
        jQuery('#secondary-menu_formation > li').css('display','block');
        break
} 

    jQuery('#secondary-menu-wrap').toggle('slide',{direction: 'up'}, 500);
        });

        jQuery('.T_logo').click(function(){
        jQuery('.secondary-menu > li').css('display','none'); 
        });
});
```

and

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('#header-menu > li').click(function(){
        jQuery('#secondary-menu-wrap').toggle('slide',{direction: 'up'}, 500).promise().done(function(){
         jQuery('.secondary-menu > li').css('display','none');               
};



switch(this.id) {
    case 'menu-item-group':
        jQuery('#secondary-menu_group > li').css('display','block');
        break;
    case 'menu-item-research':
        jQuery('#secondary-menu_research > li').css('display','block');
        break;
    case 'menu-item-projects':
        jQuery('#secondary-menu_projects > li').css('display','block');
        break;
    case 'menu-item-publications':
        jQuery('#secondary-menu_publications > li').css('display','block');
        break;
    case 'menu-item-pressroom':
        jQuery('#secondary-menu_pressroom > li').css('display','block');
        break;
    case 'menu-item-formation':
        jQuery('#secondary-menu_formation > li').css('display','block');
        break
} 

    jQuery('#secondary-menu-wrap').toggle('slide',{direction: 'up'}, 500);
        });

        jQuery('.T_logo').click(function(){
        jQuery('.secondary-menu > li').css('display','none'); 
        });
});
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: can you explain your problem properly i cant understand and if possible create a fiddle

Comment: sorry @himanshu. I tried to explain the problem better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly what you're trying to achieve, then you could simplify your code as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('#secondary-menu-wrap > ul').hide();

    $('#header-menu > li').click(function(){
        menuToShow = this.id.substring(this.id.lastIndexOf('-') + 1);

        $('#secondary-menu-wrap').slideToggle(500, function(){
            $('.secondary-menu').css('display','none');
           $('#secondary-menu-'+menuToShow).css('display', 'block');
            $(this).slideToggle(500);
        });
    }); 
});
```

At the beginning we're hiding all submenus. This will trigger upon clicking an element in the `#header-menu` list, and will store the submenu index in the `menuToShow` variable. After this, we'll fire a `slideToggle` animation on the `#secondary-menu-wrap` wrapper element (note: you were trying `toggle`, but you've also got the `slideToggle` event, and its default direction is up - so we're only passing it the duration and the function to run once completed).
Once we've slid the wrapper closed, we're making sure all the submenus are hidden, and the one matching our submenu index is made visible. At the end we toggle our wrapper back open.

JSFiddle for demonstration: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uqb56cp0/)

Comment: thanks @Gabor. I can see that this works in Fiddle but i can't do it work in my menu. I am using "jQuery UI Widgets" for wordpress so I tried to change the $ to jQuery and the 'slideToggle()' effect for 'toggle()' Is posible modify the first code that I share to wait until the toggle effect is finished?

Comment: No... I couldn't understand what is happening and I need continue with the development of the webpage to finish it as soon as posible so i only use the slide efect to show each submenu. I will try it again when I finish other things. Thanks for your help. It works fine in Fiddle so I should review my html to find the problem.